# Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials form helm Provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-helm-provider

I have tried to use the following terraform configuration:

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = aws_eks_cluster.La-Production-EKS.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(aws_eks_cluster.La-Production-EKS.certificate_authority[0].data)
    exec {
      api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
      args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", aws_eks_cluster.La-Production-EKS.id]
      command     = "aws"
    }
  }
}

### ---------------------- EKS LB Controller ----------------------

resource "helm_release" "aws-load-balancer-controller" {
  name = "aws-load-balancer-controller"

  repository = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"
  chart      = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  version    = "1.4.1"

  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.id
  }

  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = "v2.4.2"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.name"
    value = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = aws_iam_role.aws_load_balancer_controller.arn
  }

}
```

When I have used locally it proceeds without any error, however when I have tried using in our CI/CD for terraform, mainly it fails on terraform plan command on CI/CD. And I get the following output:

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

with helm_release.aws-load-balancer-controller,
on EKS-LoadBalancer-Controller.tf line 15, in resource "helm_release" "aws-load-balancer-controller":
15: resource "helm_release" "aws-load-balancer-controller" {

How to fix? I have tried to go with using:

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "$PATH_KUBECONFIG"
  }
} # And passing Gitlab CI/CD File Env Variable  as $PATH_KUBECONFIG to my Kubernetes
```

However, it still output the same error. Any tips or ideas is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried providing client_key and client_certificate? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs#credentials-config